# WordPress: Count of today's modified and published posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that suppose to count all of posts that published and edited today.

Currently I'm using a code that count modified today's posts but it's not very accurate. Sometimes it does not provide accurate statistics and beside I want to count published and modified posts.

```
function sabtfactor_su($shenase){
    $today = getdate();
    
    $s_b = get_posts(array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'author'=>$shenase,
    'numberposts'=>-1,
    'meta_key'=>'shomare_status','meta_value'=>'Example',
    'date_query' => [
        'column' => 'post_modified',
        'after'  => [
            'year'=>$today['year'],
            'month'=>$today['mon'],
            'day'=>$today['mday']-1
        ],
    ]
    ));

    return count($s_b)+0; 
}
```

1. If I delete `-1` from `'day'=>$today['mday']-1`, it will return `0`.
2. I think it's fine if I query  by `'column' => 'post_modified'` So if there is a need to add a arg for posts like `'column' => 'published',` , please advise.

Comment: What is the parameter `$shenase` for and where is `$authorid` coming from? Do you need to filter for the meta_key / meta_value?

Comment: @volkerschulz Sorry. That was mistake by me when i was posting. Edited thanks.

Comment: @volkerschulz I just need to somehow edit this code to get all new published and modified posts only for today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function returns the count of all `posts` that are `published` and have been `modified today`:

```
function sabtfactor_su() {
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND post_modified_gmt LIKE '{$today}%'";
    return (int)$wpdb->get_var($query);
}
```

To get the same result but for a specific `author_id` use:

```
function sabtfactor_su($shenase) {
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_author='%d' AND post_status='publish' AND post_modified_gmt LIKE '{$today}%'";
    return (int)$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $shenase));
}
```

And to further narrow it down to all post with a specific `meta_value` for a specific `meta_key` for a specific `author_id` use:

```
function sabtfactor_su($shenase) {
    global $wpdb;
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta ON post_id=ID AND meta_key='shomare_status' AND meta_value='Example' WHERE post_type='post' AND post_author='%d' AND post_status='publish' AND post_modified_gmt LIKE '{$today}%'";
    return (int)$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $shenase));
}
```

Comment: I didn't tested it yet, but how can I add `'meta_key'=>'shomare_status', 'meta_value'=>'Example',` part of my original code into it? Can you please edit your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @TLPMasih Find all variations above.